# Android app links work in production, but not on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, ios-universal-links, android-app-links

I have configured app links as such:

```
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:host="sharer.myapp.com" android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
```

This works fine in production, with a minor unrelated issue that I am trying to resolve which is that it doesn't open the desired page.

To debug this, I should be able to open the link from my emulator, but I can't. I have tried both regular emulator and physical device, changing the configuration of the app so that it launches the url (replaced it with myurl in the pic, but I know it is the right one cause it opens the view), opening the url from my Whatsapp instead, and changing the build variants to "release", but it never opens the app and it always goes to the webview:

[image: run config]

There is something I am not getting here, because in production it works. Can someone help me?

Btw I am using Ionic and Capacitor v5, if that matters for something.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the emulator does not go through the auto-verify stuff. If you go to the system Settings app and go to your app's page there, you should be able to manually opt into opening app links for your domain. See if that helps.

Comment: That was it, thank you very much! All I did was go into System settings > My App > Open By Default (the section where it says Allow app to open supported links) > Add my link there (it was already there, just unchecked).

Would you kindly post the answer so I can mark it as correct for others to see? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As CommonsWare pointed out, the correct solution was simply to go into the app details inside the settings and allowing the outside link of my sharer.

*System settings > My App > Open By Default (the section where it says Allow app to open supported links)* > Add my link there (it was already there, just unchecked).

Comment: Glad it worked for you!